# Drawing a regular octagon with added lines and points

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, polygon

[image]

This is what I am trying to currently draw. I however do not know how to add the purple lines or green points. I am able to draw a regular octagon with points and the outer lines by the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \newdimen\R
   \R=1.3cm
   \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \foreach \x/\l/\p in
     { 45/,
      90/,
      135/,
      180/,
      225/,
      270/,
      315/,
      360
     }
     \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (\x:\R) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I am unsure of how to add the rest.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

[image: regular octogon and lines]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        summit/.style={inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,circle,fill=black,text=white},
        innode/.style={inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,circle,fill=green!50!black,text=white},
        outnode/.style={inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,circle,fill=violet,text=white}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \newdimen\R
        \R=1.3cm
        \draw (-22.5:\R) \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,45,...,315} {  -- (\x+22.5:\R) node[summit] (\i) {} };
        
        \node[innode] at (intersection of  1--6 and 5--8) (A) {};
        \node[innode] at (intersection of  1--4 and 2--5) (B) {};
                
        \node[outnode] at (intersection of  1--2 and 5--4) (C) {};
        \node[outnode] at (intersection of  1--8 and 5--6) (D) {};
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw[green!50!black]
                (1) -- (6)
                (5) -- (8)
                (1) -- (4)
                (2) -- (5)
                (C) -- (D);
                
            \draw[violet] (C) -- (1) -- (D) -- (5) -- (C);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @polygonlink1 If you're still waiting for improvement on this question, please feel free to comment. If this answer fulfills your demand, please accept it to let know others that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Purely for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), showing how to draw a polygon, and how to define points at the intersection of straight lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path gon; gon = for i=0 upto 7: 42 dir (45i + 45/2) -- endfor cycle;

    z1 = whatever[point 0 of gon, point 1 of gon] = whatever[point 3 of gon, point 4 of gon];
    z2 = whatever[point 0 of gon, point 3 of gon] = whatever[point 1 of gon, point 4 of gon];
    z3 = whatever[point 0 of gon, point 5 of gon] = whatever[point 7 of gon, point 4 of gon];
    z4 = whatever[point 0 of gon, point 7 of gon] = whatever[point 5 of gon, point 4 of gon];

    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4);
    draw z1 -- z4;
    draw subpath (1,3) of gon -- point 0 of gon -- 
         subpath (5,7) of gon -- point 4 of gon -- cycle;

    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[red, blue]);
    draw point 0 of gon -- z1 -- point 4 of gon -- z4 -- cycle;

    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam);
    for i=1 upto 4:
        draw point i of gon;
        draw point i+4 of gon;
        draw z[i] if (i=2) or (i=3): withcolor 1/2 green fi;
    endfor

    drawoptions();
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.