# Adding points inside a regular hexagon

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs, polygon

[image]

I am trying to create this image with latex, and I specifically add the red points in the interior of the regular hexagon as well as make the outer edges of the regular hexagon blue.

I am able to create the following regular hexagon but I do not know how to color the outer edges blue or add the points in the interior (these points should specifically be on the intersection points of the diagonals):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
\newdimen\R
\R=1.3cm
\draw[red]
    (300:\R) \foreach \x in {360,60} {  -- (\x:\R) };
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
{
    \node (n\j) [dot] at (60*\j:\R) {};
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
{
\ifnum\i=1
    \foreach \j in {2,...,6}
    \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
\else
   \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
   \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
\fi
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: [I answered recently to one very related question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595397/204164) which you didn't accept. Hope you saw it. You can find there a way to compute intersections between lines, which is exactly what you're asking here. You may take great advantage in learning from the answers you receive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here it is. Using my previous answers to two of your questions, here's a way to find intersections between lines defined between nodes:

`\node at (intersection of  n2--n6 and n1--n3) (A) {};` is pretty straightforward to understand. You named your nodes n1 to n6, you then put a node named A (not mandatory to name it, but allow you to use it afterwards) at the intersection of the line through nodes n2 and n6 and the line through n1 and n3.

I let you make the remaining ones. Note that you can also do them with a foreach loop, if you want to shorten your code.

[image: another regular hexagon]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={black,circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt,text=white},
        innode/.style={inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,circle,fill=red},
        every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
        \newdimen\R
        \R=1.3cm
        
        \draw[cyan,line width=1pt] (0:\R) \foreach \x [count=\i] in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) node[dot] (n\i) {} };
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]      
            \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
                {
                \ifnum\i=1      % Part with \if is useless here, but anyway
                    \foreach \j in {2,...,6}
                    \draw (n\i.center) -- (n\j.center);
                \else
                   \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
                   \draw (n\i.center) -- (n\j.center);
                \fi
                }       
        \end{scope}

        \node[innode] at (intersection of  n2--n6 and n1--n3) (A) {};
        \node[innode] at (intersection of  n2--n5 and n1--n3) (B) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might also like a [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) version, perhaps?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path h;
    h = for t=0 upto 5: 72 dir 60t -- endfor cycle;

    z0 = whatever[point 0 of h, point 2 of h] = whatever[point 1 of h, point 5 of h];
    z1 = whatever[point 0 of h, point 2 of h] = whatever[point 1 of h, point 3 of h];
    z2 = whatever[point 5 of h, point 2 of h] = whatever[point 1 of h, point 3 of h];
    z3 = whatever[point 5 of h, point 3 of h] = whatever[point 2 of h, point 4 of h];
    z4 = whatever[point 5 of h, point 3 of h] = whatever[point 0 of h, point 4 of h];
    z5 = whatever[point 5 of h, point 2 of h] = whatever[point 0 of h, point 4 of h];
    
    draw h withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
    
    for i=0 upto 5:
        for j=i+1 upto 5:
            draw point i of h -- point j of h;
        endfor
    endfor
    
    for i=0 upto 5:
        drawdot point i of h withpen pencircle scaled 5;
        drawdot z[i]         withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor 2/3 red;
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`.